# Can not connect through ssh to my remote machine

Tags: file, ubuntu, configuration, ssh, terminal

Yesterday i restarted my remote computer only to find that i could no longer connect to it through ssh. I can connect to the computer if I'm using the computer, but when i try to on my other computer it does not work. I have tried reinstalling it but i have had no luck. Whenever i try to connect to it through a different computer, its "Connection timed out". I have also checked ssh status and it says it is running.

Also, I am kind of a beginner to this so if my terminology is off feel free to correct me.

I don't know what i should do. Any help and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the firewall is blocking port 22.

maybe some changes have been made and got applied only when you restarted the machine.

Have a look at the output of

```
iptables -L | grep ssh
```

and see if there is any info

Comment: Not sure how i would go about checking the port in the firewalls, but iptables -L | grep ssh gives me nothing.

Comment: What is in the config file? /etc/ssh/sshd_config? What is Port option set to and  what is ListenAddress set to?

Comment: This is the config file: http://pastebin.com/WkYzPvFq The port is set to 22 i believe, and the ListenAdress is #ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0

Comment: Might sound stupid but can you ping the remote machine?

Comment: Ah you were right! I dont know how, but i guess somehow my firewall was blocking my port! Thank you soooo much!